# draw webcam video screenshot to canvas without mirroring canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, canvas

Okay so I am displaying the webcam feed from a computer though the video element in HTML and i'm mirroring it so it seems more like it should. When I take a screenshot and display it on a canvas the image is back to how it originally is, not mirrored. Now I could mirror the canvas so then it would look just like the video, but I am also trying to draw other things on the canvas based on where the cursor is. I know I could just mirror where the cursor is so it seems like you are just drawing were it should be but i'm going to be drawing lots of things on the canvas so it would be annoying. I am wondering if I can just essentially mirror the video's feed before its put on the canvas so that I won't have to mirror everything else?

Displaying webcam in video element:

```js
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
 
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;
 
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
}
 
function handleVideo(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}
```

and mirroring video element with CSS:

```css
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
```

Screenshot onto canvas:

```js
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Instead of using css to mirror your video you can do it directly on the canvas : `ctx.scale(-1, 1)`

Comment: That's what I am trying to avoid. I'm showing the webcam on the video first so I would need to mirror it first if I want it to look like what I do. When I put the screenshot on the canvas I could mirror with that but if i did that I wouldn't be able to draw things based on cursor placement.

Comment: Just set the mirroring for when you draw the video frame then revert it to normal? `ctx.scale(-1,1); ctx.translate(yourVid.videoWidth, 0); ctx.drawImage(yourVid, x,y); ctx.scale(-1,1); ctx.translate(-yourVid.videoWidth, 0); ctx.doYourOtherDrawings();` or alternatively, `ctx.setTransform(-1,0,0,1,yourVid.videoWidth,0); ctx.drawImage(yourVid, 0,0);
 ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); ctx.doYourOtherDrawings();`

Comment: ohhh yes. That does work. Cant believe I didn't see that. Thanks a lot! Good stuff.